# is it possible to undelete Shadow Copies?

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to undelete / recover shadow copies which are deleted by

```
vssadmin delete shadows
```

command on windows7?

Comment: No, when they are gone then they are no more recoverable.

Comment: thanks  for the information. Shame that its not possible to recover it.

Comment: I suggest you make images. Those you control yourself. Restore points can be very volatile. This is a good imaging program ==> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73828-imaging-free-macrium.html?ltr=I